# How can I save my numbers in an array to have bigger output

Tags: c

I wrote this code to calculate factorials, but it can't calculate more than 20 numbers. How can I use arrays to have for example more than 500 numbers in the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int result = 1;
    int f;
    int i;
    int as = 1;
    scanf("%d", &f);    

    for (i = 1; i <= f; i++) {
        as *= i;
    }
    printf("%d", as);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays have nothing to do with this problem at all. I was once told that I was good at Physics, not because of my exams but because of my questions. You are asking a very bad question that indicates that you need to understand a lot more than just arrays. Why do you say that it cannot calculate more than 20 numbers? You should start there. And note that `int main()` is an invalid signature for *main*.

Comment: see this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The factorial function grows exponentially.  You will need to use an extended-precision package (or write your own) to handle larger factorials.

Comment: if you can compute `20!` then you must be using 64-bit integers. 32-bit integers can only hold `12!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/) link,
Following is a simple solution where we use an array to store individual digits of the result. The idea is to use basic mathematics for multiplication. 
The following is detailed algorithm for finding factorial.

**factorial(n)**

1) Create an array ‘`res[]`’ of MAX size where MAX is number of maximum digits in output.

2) Initialize value stored in `‘res[]’` as 1 and initialize ‘res_size’ (size of ‘res[]’) as 1.

3) Do following for all numbers from x = 2 to n.

……a) Multiply x with res[] and update res[] and res_size to store the multiplication result.

How to multiply a number ‘x’ with the number stored in res[]?

The idea is to use simple school mathematics. We one by one multiply x with every digit of `res[]`. The important point to note here is digits are multiplied from rightmost digit to leftmost digit. If we store digits in same order in `res[]`, then it becomes difficult to update `res[]` without extra space. That is why `res[]` is maintained in reverse way, i.e., digits from right to left are stored.

**multiply(res[], x)**

1) Initialize carry as 0.

2) Do following for i = 0 to res_size – 1

….a) Find value of res[i] * x + carry. Let this value be prod.

….b) Update res[i] by storing last digit of prod in it.

….c) Update carry by storing remaining digits in carry.

3) Put all digits of carry in res[] and increase res_size by number of digits in carry.

**Example to show working of multiply(res[], x)
A number 5189 is stored in res[] as following.**

```
res[] = {9, 8, 1, 5}
x = 10

Initialize carry = 0;

i = 0, prod = res[0]*x + carry = 9*10 + 0 = 90.
res[0] = 0, carry = 9

i = 1, prod = res[1]*x + carry = 8*10 + 9 = 89
res[1] = 9, carry = 8

i = 2, prod = res[2]*x + carry = 1*10 + 8 = 18
res[2] = 8, carry = 1

i = 3, prod = res[3]*x + carry = 5*10 + 1 = 51
res[3] = 1, carry = 5

res[4] = carry = 5
res[] = {0, 9, 8, 1, 5}
```

Below is the implementation of above algorithm.

```
// C++ program to compute factorial of big numbers
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Maximum number of digits in output
#define MAX 500

int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size)

// This function finds factorial of large numbers and prints them
void factorial(int n)
{
    int res[MAX];

    // Initialize result
    res[0] = 1;
    int res_size = 1;

    // Apply simple factorial formula n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4...*n
    for (int x=2; x<=n; x++)
        res_size = multiply(x, res, res_size);

    cout << "Factorial of given number is n";
    for (int i=res_size-1; i>=0; i--)
        cout << res[i];
}

// This function multiplies x with the number represented by res[].
// res_size is size of res[] or number of digits in the number represented
// by res[]. This function uses simple school mathematics for multiplication.
// This function may value of res_size and returns the new value of res_size
int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size)
{
    int carry = 0;  // Initialize carry

    // One by one multiply n with individual digits of res[]
    for (int i=0; i<res_size; i++)
    {
        int prod = res[i] * x + carry;
        res[i] = prod % 10;  // Store last digit of 'prod' in res[]
        carry  = prod/10;    // Put rest in carry
    }

    // Put carry in res and increase result size
    while (carry)
    {
        res[res_size] = carry%10;
        carry = carry/10;
        res_size++;
    }
    return res_size;
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    factorial(100);
    return 0;
}
```

This links also may help you:

https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7349/computing-factorials-of-a-huge-number-in-cc-a-tutorial

Comment: @a.nekoo if it solved your problem, you can mark it as an accepted answer!:) ur welcome ;).